# SciKit Learn ColumnTransformer - Prevent Prefix? (v. 1.0.2)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

When I use sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer and try to make the result into a Pandas DataFrame, I noticed that it automatically appends a prefix to the column name.

Ex:

```
transformer = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(), ['Color', 'Size'])
    ],
     remainder='passthrough'
)

transformed = transformer.fit_transform(df)

transformed_df = pd.DataFrame(transformed, columns=transformer.get_feature_names_out())

print(transformed_df.columns)
>> onehot__color_red, onehot__color_blue, onehot__size_small, onehot__size_big,  remainder__cost
```

Is there a way to prevent this? Or is there a specific reason why its supposed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

By default `ColumnTransformer` has `verbose_feature_names_out=True`. Set it to `False` to disable the prefixing behaviour.

> **verbose_feature_names_out** (bool), *default=True*
> If `True`, `ColumnTransformer.get_feature_names_out` will prefix all feature names
> with the name of the transformer that generated that feature. If
> `False`, `ColumnTransformer.get_feature_names_out` will not prefix any
> feature names and will error if feature names are not unique.

[Link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer)